# Exactly when is data that is written to a file available for reading?

Tags: linux, file, io, buffer, posix

The man page for `write` states:

```
   POSIX  requires  that  a  read(2)  which can be proved to occur after a
   write() has returned returns the new data.  Note that not all  filesys‐
   tems are POSIX conforming.
```

What exactly does "proved to occur" mean here? If process 1 `write`s data to a file descriptor on an ext4 filesystem, and process 2 calls `read` on that same file immediately after the `write` returns, does that mean that process 2 is guaranteed to get the data written by process 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [POSIX wording](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) is marginally more clear, at least on the separate process part:

> If a read() of file data can be proven (by any means) to occur after a write() of the data, it must reflect that write(), even if the calls are made by different processes.

The proof basically just means that you can show the order is not arbitrary (due to a race condition).

If process 2 happens to call `read` immediately after the write occurs, then it's not technically guaranteed to get the data.

However, if process 1 wrote something and then toggled a mutex, sent a signal, or performed any kind of operation that process 2 may directly or indirectly have observed before reading (even if it's just observing a change in filesize caused by the write itself), then the `read` is required to return that written data.

I don't know if/how the distinction is leveraged in practice, but it does for example mean that the OS can merge two sequential writes without having to take care to provide an intermediate result to anyone who just happened to read in the middle of them.